# Android java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem: I'm currently programming an Android Scan software. So I wanted to implement the SDK for the Scanner(Datalogic). When I implement the oldest Version (1.12) the app doesn't crash, but when I implement the newest Version for my device(1.17) the App crashes and says:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

I've done every step that is here explained: https://datalogic.github.io/android/overview (Maven dependency)

It seems that the App crashes when I'm trying to obtain an instance of [BarcodeManager Class](https://datalogic.github.io/android-sdk-docs/reference/com/datalogic/decode/BarcodeManager.html). But somehow not with the 1.12 SDK.

This is my build.gradle(App) dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.datalogic:datalogic-android-sdk:1.17'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

And this is my build.gradle (project):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the dependency twice in your project or somehow it's getting added ?

Comment: No, I've added in the build.grandle (App) this: `implementation 'com.github.datalogic:datalogic-android-sdk:1.17' ` and in the  build.grandle (project) this: `maven {url "https://jitpack.io" }`

Comment: Can you clean your project and try it once and let me know.

Comment: I have cleaned it and rebuild it, still the same problem.

Comment: Any jar files in your libs folder?

Comment: No, I have only added this dependency... nothing more

Comment: I have tried to add the dependency and initialize the BarcodeManager class but it's not crashing for me  Might be still some reference of older sdk is available in your workspace.

Comment: I've installed the Skorpion X4 driver, so I can start the app dircet on the device... is that the Problem?

Comment: I dont think so